# POO en Java - Crear instancia en clase hijo desde la clase padre

Tags: java, poo

Supongamos la clase ClasePadre que se utilizará como medio para formular la base del resto de clases de una aplicación, y supongamos una clase llamada ClaseHijo que heredará de la clase padre.

En ClasePadre tenemos un método estático que realiza ciertas operaciones y genera una nueva instancia de si mismo y lo devuelve. Lo que quisiera conseguir y no se me ocurre como implementarlo es que en ClaseHijo, al llamar a este método heredado de ClasePadre la instancia sea un objeto de tipo ClaseHijo (no de ClasePadre).

El objetivo de todo esto es tener una clase llamada DataModel que servirá como base a todos los modelos de datos de mi aplicación, se conectará a un SQLite y recogerá los datos. Estoy implementando un método estático llamado findById que busca un registro concreto en la base de datos, mapea los datos en una variable y devuelve una instancia de la clase con los datos recogidos. A modo de ejemplo:

```
public static DataModel findById(String id){
    DataModel aux = new DataModel();
    /* ... búsqueda en SQLite según el id... */
    return aux;
}
```

En este código obtendremos una excepción dado que la variable admin es de tipo Usuario, no de tipo DataModel:

```
class Usuario extends DataModel{
    protected String table = 'users';
}

int main(){
    Usuario admin = Usuario.findById("1");
}
```

Aquí radica la cuestión, ¿como conseguir que la clase devuelva una instancia de si misma? ¿Puedo hacer esto? Es decir, cuando utilice el método findById en la clase Usuario me devuelva una instancia de Usuario no de DataModel.

Mil gracias!

Comment: Hola @LordVermiis, hasta donde yo sé Java no permite hacer override a un método estático y la única forma de instanciar un objeto nuevo es pasando por el constructor, así que tal como lo tienes planteado, me parece imposible. Creo que te convendría cambiar cómo estas orientando tu problema y mirar algún patrón de diseño. Puede que [Factory](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/factory-kit) te ayude.

Comment: La idea no es hacer override al método estático, sino que el método estático me devuelva una instancia de la clase Usuario (o la clase que sea)  en vez de una instancia de la clase DataModel, tengo casi resuelto este tema declarando la clase padre `public class DataModel<T>` así puedo acceder desde DataModel a la clase hija. Sin embargo el mayor problema que estoy teniendo ahora es acceder a la variable table. En cualquier caso voy a revisar el Factory que me comentas a ver si me puede ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es posible lograr que el método findById de la clase DataModel devuelva una instancia de la clase que lo invoca en lugar de una instancia de DataModel. Para lograr esto, debes utilizar el mecanismo de métodos estáticos polimórficos en Java.

Puedes usar el Factory Method.

El Factory Method te permite definir una interfaz para crear objetos, pero permite que las subclases decidan qué clase concreta instanciar.

En la clase DataModel, declara un método estático llamado findById con el tipo de retorno como DataModel:

```
public class DataModel {
    protected String table;

    public static DataModel findById(String id) {
        DataModel aux = new DataModel();
        return aux;
    }
}
```

En la clase Usuario, sobrescribe el método findById y devuelve una instancia de Usuario en lugar de DataModel:

```
public class Usuario extends DataModel {
    protected String table = "users";

    public static Usuario findById(String id) {
        Usuario aux = new Usuario();
        return aux;
    }
}
```

cuando llames al método findById desde la clase Usuario, se utilizará la implementación específica de Usuario, y se devolverá una instancia de Usuario tal que así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Usuario admin = Usuario.findById("1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En Orientación a objetos la Herencia se supone es utilizada para definir familias de objetos, esto quiere decir que por ejemplo si tienes un Objeto Base y uno extendido, el extendido es todo lo del base más algunas particularidades. En el ejemplo quieres que la clase base tenga acceso a la hija, en herencia los accesos generalmente son en el otro sentido (para justamente sacar provecho a la herencia). Hay un riesgo de dependencia circular en eso que mencionas.

Respecto a lo estático o no estático, la data estática permanece inalterable independiente de las instancias de objetos que existan.

Te aconsejo que primero leas un poco acerca de herencia y data estática. En el ejemplo estás mezclando la tarea de buscar objetos con la representación de los mismo, y el almacenamiento. Un buen sistema orientado objetos separa tareas en objetos, encapsula la información y trabaja en base a colaboración.

:)